# when timing a command execution time with sudo, `time` should be before `sudo` or after `sudo`?

Tags: sudo, time

when timing a command execution time with `sudo`, `time` should be before `sudo` or after `sudo`?

```
time sudo command
```

or

```
sudo time command
```

which one is correct?

the output seems very different to me

```
    [esolve@xxt ~]$ sudo time ls
    193.144.21.131_udp.folder  lockfile         run_udp.sh    udp_folder
    50IP.txt                   my_ip_host_site  send_udp_log  udp_receiver
    ip_each_site               raw_udp_client   ssh.log
    0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed ?%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 3088maxresident)k
    0inputs+0outputs (0major+236minor)pagefaults 0swaps


    [esolve@xxt ~]$ time sudo ls        
    193.144.21.131_udp.folder  lockfile         run_udp.sh    udp_folder
    50IP.txt                   my_ip_host_site  send_udp_log  udp_receiver
    ip_each_site               raw_udp_client   ssh.log

    real    0m0.004s
    user    0m0.003s
    sys     0m0.002s
    [esolve@xxt ~]$
```

why they are like this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`time sudo command` executes your shell's `time` builtin if it has one, whereas `sudo time command` always executes the `time` executable in the program search path (`$PATH`).

`time sudo command` includes the time taken by the `sudo` command, whereas `sudo time command` doesn't.

You should use `sudo time command`, because `sudo`'s processing time is small but not always negligible, and its wall clock time may be a lot larger if the user needs to enter a password.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like on a Debian Stretch does not work "sudo time"

```
# sudo time ls
sudo: time: command not found

# time sudo ls
created

real    0m0,007s
user    0m0,002s
sys     0m0,006s
```

On Debian stretch:

```
# whereis time
time: /usr/include/time.h /usr/share/man/man7/time.7.gz /usr/share/man/man3/time.3am.gz /usr/share/man/man2/time.2.gz
```

On Debian jessie:

```
# whereis time
time: /usr/bin/time /usr/include/time.h /usr/share/man/man3/time.3am.gz /usr/share/man/man1/time.1.gz /usr/share/man/man2/time.2.gz /usr/share/man/man7/time.7.gz
```

Comment: It works if you have `time` in your `PATH`, as mentioned in Gilles’ answer; you need to install the `time` package.